# Socket.io only successfully connects if window opens before server starts

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I've been trying to resolve a really strange Socket.io bug.

If I open the page on the client while the server is running, it will fail to connect with the message:

> universalModuleDefinition:3 WebSocket connection to
>   'ws://localhost:4000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=f6LwPIDZubiPKE-TAAAA'
>   failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

If I then restart the server, while leaving the page open, it connects without issue.

**app.js**

```
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
require('./socket')(server);

// More code here

server.listen(app.get('port'))
```

**socket.js**

```
const io = require('socket.io');
const jackrabbit = require(`jackrabbit`);
const rabbit = jackrabbit(process.env.RABBIT_URI);
const exchange = rabbit.default();

function Socket (app) {
  this.io = io(app);
  this.io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.emit('sync');
    socket.on('room', room => {
      socket.join(room);
    });
  })

  this.queue = exchange.queue({ name: 'worker.socket' });
  this.queue.consume(this.onMessage.bind(this), { noAck: true });
}

Socket.prototype.onMessage = function (message) {
  this.io.to(message.report).emit('photo', message.photo);
}

module.exports = function (app) {
  return new Socket(app);
}
```

**client**

```
var socket = io.connect();

socket.on('connect', function () {
  // This gets triggered every time (after the error above)
  console.log('Connected');
  // This is never logged by the server
  socket.emit('room', value); // value set by template engine
});

socket.on('sync', function(){
  // will not execute first time I connect, but if I restart
  // the server, it runs no problem
  alert('Synced with server'); 
})

socket.on('photo', function(data) {
  // also will not be run the first time, but works if the
  // server is restarted when the page is open
})
```

**Edit:**

I've tried rewriting it to

1. Initialise socket.io within app.js, then pass it to the socket controller
2. Run `server.listen` before requiring socket.js
3. Initialising the client after a timeout
4. Setting the transport method on the client strictly to `websocket`

None of these methods have worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution to my problem (actually not an issue with any of the code I posted). I was using the `compression` middleware for Express, which appears to break socket.io. Solution was to add the following:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // Disable compression for socket.io
  if (req.originalUrl.indexOf('socket.io') > -1) {
    return next();
  }

  compression()(req, res, next);
});
```